# how to reach my locahost DB from android phone

Tags: android, xampp, localhost

I have developed an Android and now I want to test it in my real phone 
this app has a webserivice for user reg. and login, also it has a xampp server hosting my DB and a forum which I access from the app.

can soembody plz help to figure out why I can't use it in my device

here is my logcat

```
03-10 17:54:56.360: E/SensorManager(2377): thread start
03-10 17:54:56.555: E/SpannableStringBuilder(2377): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-10 17:54:56.555: E/SpannableStringBuilder(2377): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-10 17:56:06.415: E/SpannableStringBuilder(2377): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-10 17:56:06.415: E/SpannableStringBuilder(2377): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at com.mohammed.watzIslam.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:44)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at com.mohammed.watzIslam.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:39)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at com.mohammed.watzIslam.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:59)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-10 17:56:12.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You're doing network stuff on the main thread. Don't do that. Use AsyncTasks instead.